# Django 1.4 static files problems and don't render at other urls of my project

Tags: python, django, static-files, django-staticfiles, django-1.4

Here are my settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/tony/Documents/mysite/mysite/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
"/home/tony/Documents/mysite/mysite/static/",
)
```

And here I refer my stylesheet(This gives me an error):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css" />
```

And the error in the log:

```
[06/Apr/2012 13:36:09] "GET /css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2193
[06/Apr/2012 13:36:09] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2193
```

How I thought I fixed it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}static/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}static/css/style.css" />
```

And it worked until I made another view-:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def test(request):
    return render_to_response('test.html')
```

And in the template I added the {% extends 'base/base.html' %} and what do I get in the logs? this:

```
[06/Apr/2012 13:46:55] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 964
[06/Apr/2012 13:46:55] "GET /test/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2229
[06/Apr/2012 13:46:55] "GET /test/static/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2229
```

Notice the /test/? It doesn't load the css.
Any idea why?(I never had this problem with django1.3)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I thought CSS should go into as media and not as static files

Comment: @starcorn: this has been changed. Media files are now the files that have been uploaded, static files are CSS/JS/images that are really part of the site itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `RequestContext` to render your template, so the context processors aren't being run and therefore `STATIC_URL` is empty.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the following does not fix your problem because `STATIC_URL` should contain `/static/`, you don't want to write it yourself anywhere:

```
"{{ STATIC_URL }}static/css/reset.css"
```

Now, if you have `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your template but the `/static/` does not show up in the templates then I think you're missing the template context processor for `STATIC_URL`.

Add `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. For example, like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

If `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is in your settings file already then you should add it to what's already there.

Also, note that `STATIC_URL` ends in a slash so you'll need to remove the first slash after `{{ STATIC_URL }}` here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/reset.css" />
```

---

Lastly, your `STATIC_ROOT` is most likely not what you intended. It should be:

```
"/home/tony/Documents/mysite/mysite/static/"
```

This is the location where the static files will be placed when you run the `collectstatic` command. See [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in the Django documentation.

Comment: Hey Simeon... I've tried this also TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
) but it doesn't work

Comment: But did you make sure this is not causing the problem? If you write `{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/reset.css` then it should not be possible to have a request to `/css/reset.css`.

Comment: Also, what's the URL of the file now? Can you view it when you go to `/static/css/reset.css` in your browser?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" /> is the link... and yes it shows me the contents of my stylesheet

Comment: I mean, when you add `/static/css/reset.css` in the address bar of your browser, such as `http://localhost:8000/static/css/reset.css`. Can you see the file there? If not, under what URL can you view the file, if any?

Comment: Hmm, have you checked that `{{ STATIC_URL }}` has a value in the template (for example, what does the HTML look like)? Are you modifying `STATIC_URL` somewhere else? Have you restarted the server after adding the template context processor? Otherwise I can't think of another reason why `STATIC_URL` would be empty.

Comment: Yes I did restart it, and in the html it's in the head tag as it's supposed to be... the wierd thing is its a brand new project untouched and i get this problem