# Load CSS/images in Django

Tags: css, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've read the official Django Docs and many other posts here in SO. Still I'm unable to figure out the way to load my CSS files in HTML pages. I'm running `Django 1.4`. Here is my whole structure of `mysite` project having `auth` as the app.

```
mysite/
      manage.py
      settings.py
      __init__.py
      urls.py
      auth/
          __init__.py
          forms.py
          models.py
          views.py
      templates/
               index.html
               home.html
      media/
           common.css
```

How can I load my `common.css` file in `index` and `home` template files?

Comment: Hope this may help :

[reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042469/django-1-4-static-files-problems-and-dont-render-at-other-urls-of-my-project)

[reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026409/django-site-in-developement-css-not-loading-for-all-pages)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `static files`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

You need to:

1. add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to your installed apps
2. put your files in the `static` directory
3. set `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` in your settings
4. use the `STATIC_URL` variable or the `static` templatetag in your templates

`{% load staticfiles %}` and then `<link href="{% static "common.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

In your production environment you'll then need to collect the static files